# Denote meaning of 'conference' in question?

Tags: discussion

I have read a number of questions that ask about papers at conferences. There is clearly a massive divide over the meaning of 'conference' in the sense of publications, and I think it is large enough to have a significant on the answer to such questions. Often there is a comment at some point mentioning the difference/assuming the wrong meaning, but this is not always the case. I've started to wonder whether there should be something to clearly denote which meaning is intended by the OP, both for those answering the question and for any readers who might not be aware of the difference (and might potentially act on advice that isn't applicable to them).

That is, **should there be a method of denoting the intended meaning of 'conference' in a question?** I am not aware of one currently in use.

**If so, what should that method be?** The best option I can think of would be to have two tags to use (conference=publication, conference<>publication), although this perhaps isn't the intended purpose of tags.